# How can I edit smart vector object in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I copied objects from my Illustrator project (several objects in multiple layers) and pasted them in Photoshop using the smart object option. The image appeared with the diagonal lines in one smart vector object layer, but all file, edit options have been grayed out and all buttons are not responding. I want to apply some noise effects to my image.

Comment: Confirm placement, then the options should be available again.

Comment: @KMSTR I'd like to add that confirmation is most easily given using the `Enter` or `Return` keys.

Comment: ...using a Keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

This might be due to lack of confirmation when you paste your objects in Photoshop, also, if what you want is to edit that smart object back in Illustrator all you have to do is to double click on the layer in the layers panel.

You can find a video directly in Adobe's support website, which explains in depth the usage of smart objects in Photoshop: https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/create-smart-objects.html